# os.makedirs wrongly catches extension-less files for directory on macOS

Tags: python, macos, directory, file-extension

I am trying to create directories with the same name as files. There is a file: `readme` and it has no extension. It gets caught in the `os.makedirs(directory)` claiming that the file exists.

```py
source = "Users/me/Desktop/parent"
dirpaths = ['readme', 'index', 'robots']

def func(directory,source=source):
   directory = os.path.join(source,directory) #
   os.makedirs(directory)

a = [func(directory) for directory in dirpaths]
>>> FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/Users/me/Desktop/parent/readme'
```

I changed the line with # to this:

```py
directory = os.path.join(source,directory+"/")
>>> NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/me/Desktop/parent/readme/'
```

How can I make the directory when an extension-less file of the same name exists?

Python 3.7.3

Turns out, macOS treats directory and extension-less files as the same. I tried moving a folder named `readme` to `parent` but it refused.

[image]

```
os.path.isfile(source + "/" + "readme") 
True 
os.path.isfile(source + "/" + "readme/") 
False 
os.path.isdir(source + "/" + "readme/") 
False 
os.path.isdir(source + "/" + "readme") 
False
```

If there is a difference here, can it be used for creating too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories are only special types of files. Specifically, they are just files where the [`file mode bits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mode) indicate that the file is a directory (see the bitmask [`stat.S_ISDIR`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISDIR)). For example, a directory's mode as an octal number might typically be `0o40755` and a regular file `0o100644`.

On most filesystems (including macOS), you may not have a directory and a regular file with the same name within the same directory, nor may you have filename which includes the path separator character. This is in contrast to an object store, such as [s3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), which is *not* actually a filesystem.

See for yourself, that the same [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) is taken whether you specify a trailing slash or not:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.makedirs("./example")
>>> os.stat('./example/').st_ino == os.stat('./example').st_ino
True
```

Comment: "you may not have a directory and a regular file with" regular files ? I count `robots.txt` as regular. `readme` as irregular.

Comment: ["Regular file"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISREG) has a pretty specific meaning which indicates not a directory, symbolic link, special device etc..  it's not really related to the filename at all.

Comment: os.path.isfile(source + "/" + "readme") True os.path.isfile(source + "/" + "readme/")  False os.path.isdir(source + "/" + "readme/") False  os.path.isdir(source + "/" + "readme") False. For readability:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCa2U.png Can't this difference be leveraged ?

Comment: I suggest you `print(os.path.isfile.__doc__)` to see what it is actually doing there.